# How to get all collectionview cell index inside tableview cell using Protocol in Swift

Tags: swift, tableview, cell

I am using collectionview inside tableview cell. so when collectionview cell button is clicked then present viewcontroller i am using protocol..

code for tableviewcell and delegate:

```
protocol CustomCellDelegate: class {
func sharePressed(cell: ProposalTableVIewCell)
}

class ProposalTableVIewCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource {


@IBOutlet weak var attetchmentsCollectionview: UICollectionView!

var delegate: CustomCellDelegate?

public var bidAttatchment: Array<Get_attachments>?


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    
    return bidAttatchment?.count ?? 0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "AttatchmentCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! AttatchmentCollectionViewCell
    
    let attatchBid = bidAttatchment?[indexPath.item]
    
    cell.attatchmentLbl.text = attatchBid?.filename
    
    cell.openBtn.tag = indexPath.item
    
    cell.openBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(connected(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    
    return cell
 }
@objc func connected(sender: UIButton){

delegate?.sharePressed(cell: self)

}
```

**code for viewcontroller:** when i press `sharePressed` getting only collectionview's first cell value.. how to get all cells value.. please do let me know

```
 class ViewMyAppliedReqVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate, CustomCellDelegate{


func sharePressed(cell: ProposalTableVIewCell) {
    
    guard let index = tableView.indexPath(for: cell)?.row else { return }
    let name = getBitDetails?.result?.bid?.get_attachments?[index].filename// always getting only first cell value
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ViewProposalTableVIewCell1", for: indexPath) as! ViewProposalTableVIewCell1
    
    cell.bidAttatchment = getBitDetails?.result?.bid?.get_attachments
    cell.delegate = self
    cell.attetchmentsCollectionview.reloadData()
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are always getting same index because you are taking out index of "ProposalTableVIewCell" and this is tableView cell. And collectionView cells are in the same tableView cell.

Solution:
Take another parameter in protocol function like below for storing index of collection cell

```
    protocol CustomCellDelegate: class {
       func sharePressed(cell: ProposalTableVIewCell,collectionCellIndex:Int)
    }


    func sharePressed(cell: ProposalTableVIewCell, collectionCellIndex:Int) {
    
       guard let index = tableView.indexPath(for: cell)?.row else { return }
       let name = getBitDetails?.result?.bid?.get_attachments?[collectionCellIndex].filename// This will return index of collection cell
    }


   @objc func connected(sender: UIButton){

      delegate?.sharePressed(cell: self,collectionCellIndex: sender.tag )

   }
```